# SOQL date literals

Tags: soql

I want to get records last modified date is > 7.

like `if(audList.LastModifiedDate  >  (Date.today()  -  7)){`
Can we do this with date literal?

Answer (score 5):

If your question is related to SOQL queries, its possible.
There is a query literal

> LAST_N_DAYS:n

With this you can achieve your requirement.

For example, if your date field is **MyDateField**, your query condition becomes

> MyDateField >= LAST_N_DAYS:7

Comment: A list of all date literals that you can use is covered in the documentation page [SOQL date formats and literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm). There are a few 'extra' date literals that can be used as well, like `N_DAYS_AGO:x`. All of the 'relative date values' listed in [Relative Date Values for Filter Criteria](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_dates.htm&language=en&type=0) should work just fine in SOQL as well.

Comment: @user41206 If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `Date.today()  -  7`

Use `date.today().addDays(-7)`